# In Django how to decrypt the session id in database and in cookie with my SECRET_KEY?

Tags: python, django

I created one Django application with below settings - (for cookie base session)

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

Then I got a session id

```
sessionid=.eJxrYJk6gwECaqdo9PDGJ5aWZMSXFqcWxWemTOlhMjSY0iOEJJiUmJydmgeU0UzJSsxLz9dLzs8rKcpM0gMp0YPKFuv55qek5jjB1PIjGZCRWJwxpUfDMNUk1STJ1MLc0tLczDLNyMg0ydDQzDTJzCjZ0jg50SLR3NDc3DzReEqpHgBcETf7:1eVt50:xtWtUp9mwcxusxtg6fZB_tHzlYw
```

With another setting (for database-backed sesisons)

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
```

I got below encrypted string in database:

```
gzc9c9nwwraqhbdsk9xg935ypkqp7ecs|MmExZWI0NjZjYzIwNDYyZDhjNWVmODJlNmMwNjI0ZmJmMjQ4MTljNDp7Il9hdXRoX3VzZXJfaWQiOiIxMCIsIl9hdXRoX3VzZXJfYmFja2VuZCI6ImRqYW5nby5jb250cmliLmF1dGguYmFja2VuZHMuTW9kZWxCYWNrZW5kIiwiX2F1dGhfdXNlcl9oYXNoIjoiMWU0ZTRiNTg3OTk3NjlmMjI1YjExNjViNjJjOTNjYThhNzE3NzdhMyIsImxhc3RfbG9naW4iOjIyMjJ9
```

I want to know what is inside both the encrypted strings.

1. How can I decrypt both?
2. Which encryption algorithm django uses for encryption?
3. Where can I set the encryption algorithms?

It will be great, if anyone can give me a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation about signing values using the secret key can be found at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signing/

Looking at the session id string that looks like a complex value:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signing/#protecting-complex-data-structures

```
>>> from django.core import signing
>>> value = signing.dumps({"foo": "bar"})
>>> value
'eyJmb28iOiJiYXIifQ:1NMg1b:zGcDE4-TCkaeGzLeW9UQwZesciI'
>>> signing.loads(value)
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

So try to do `signing.loads(session_id)`

But that can fail also due to the wrong salt. Just read up about Django sessions to find out more about storage. Especially https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/ and how to implement your own serializer/storage

Answer (score 4):

First off, I would not recommend you use `PickleSerializer` unless you have a good reason to change the default session serializer and understand [the security implications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions).

The cookies you have aren't encrypted, they're just encoded as url-safe base64 (optionally compressed with zlib) and then signed:

```
In [8]: import base64

In [9]: base64.urlsafe_b64decode('MmExZWI0NjZjYzIwNDYyZDhjNWVmODJlNmMwNjI0ZmJmMjQ4MTljNDp7Il9hdXRoX3VzZXJfaWQiOiIxMCIsIl9hdXRoX3VzZXJfYmFja2VuZCI6ImRqYW5nby5jb250cmliLmF1dGguYmFja2V
  ...   uZHMuTW9kZWxCYWNrZW5kIiwiX2F1dGhfdXNlcl9oYXNoIjoiMWU0ZTRiNTg3OTk3NjlmMjI1YjExNjViNjJjOTNjYThhNzE3NzdhMyIsImxhc3RfbG9naW4iOjIyMjJ9')
Out[9]: '2a1eb466cc20462d8c5ef82e6c0624fbf24819c4:{"_auth_user_id":"10","_auth_user_backend":"django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend","_auth_user_hash":"1e4e4b58799769f225b1165b62c93ca8a71777a3","last_login":2222}'

In [10]: base64.urlsafe_b64decode('.eJxrYJk6gwECaqdo9PDGJ5aWZMSXFqcWxWemTOlhMjSY0iOEJJiUmJydmgeU0UzJSsxLz9dLzs8rKcpM0gMp0YPKFuv55qek5jjB1PIjGZCRWJwxpUfDMNUk1STJ1MLc0tLczDLNyMg0ydDQz
   ...   DTJzCjZ0jg50SLR3NDc3DzReEqpHgBcETf7').decode('zlib')
Out[10]: '\x80\x04\x95\x98\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94(\x8c\r_auth_user_id\x94\x8c\x0210\x94\x8c\x12_auth_user_backend\x94\x8c)django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend\x94\x8c\x0f_auth_user_hash\x94\x8c(1e4e4b58799769f225b1165b62c93ca8a71777a3\x94u.'
```

This is all handled by your [`SESSION_ENGINE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views):

```
from importlib import import_module
from django.conf import settings

SessionStore = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE).SessionStore

session_data = SessionStore().decode('.eJxrYJk6gwECaqdo9PDGJ5aWZMSXFq......')
```